# Magnetic Flux Density

Tags: electromagnetism

A refresher please, can anyone provide: does magnetic flux density trail off in weakness to follow an inverse square rule? My question is predicated on Gauss's flux theorem for gravity.

Comment: Magnetic flux density of *what*? There is no magnetic analog of a point charge.

Comment: Im looking for an answer to how flux lines seperate in increasing distance the further away from the magnetic source

Answer (score 0):

The magnetic field of a magnetic dipole decreases as the inverse cube of the distance.

The magnetic field of a straight current-carrying wire decreases as the inverse of the distance from the wire.

I don't know of any magnetic fields that are inverse-square, except for the fields of theoretical-but-unobserved magnetic monopoles.

Comment: inverse CUBE thanks for the right answer much appreciated